# Iterating through a Hash while Updating a Counter

Tags: ruby

I have a hash:

```
students = {
  class1: 11,
  class2: 24,
  class3: 38,
  class4: 62
}
```

I want there to be four lines of output:

```
1) 11  
2) 35 #11 + 24  
3) 73 #35 + 38  
4) 135 #73 + 62
```

It goes through each element, and adds a value to a counter, printing each iteration as it goes. I need something like:

```
students.each do |key, value|
  value + counter = total
  puts total
end
```

but I have no idea how to do it. Please advise.

Comment: This operation is called [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Scan_higher_order_function](*Prefix Sum* or *Scan*), which is strangely missing from the [`Enumerable`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html) API. It is closely related to [http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)](*Fold*), which is available in Ruby as [`Enumerable#inject`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this, but I will suggest a way that will teach you a few different things about Ruby. This is also a very Ruby-like way to address this problem.

**Code**

```
students = {
class1: 11,
class2: 24,
class3: 38,
class4: 62 }

students.reduce(0) do |tot, (k,v)|
  tot += v
  puts k[/\d+/] + ") #{tot}"
  tot
end
1) 11
2) 35
3) 73
4) 135
```

**Explanation**

I've used [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a. `inject`) because that method is convenient for totaling a collection of numbers, using a variable  (here `tot`) that maintains the running total within the block.  That's just what you need.

Aside: you will learn a lot be reading the documentation for Ruby methods.  Methods are referenced like this: `SomeClass#method` or `SomeModule#method`.  Here, `reduce` is an instance method of the module `Enumerable`.  `students` is an instance of the class `Hash`, but that class "mixes-in" (includes) the instance methods of the module `Enumerable`.

The object `tot` is a `Fixnum` that is initialized to `reduce`'s argument, which here is zero.  (If no initial value were given, the initial value from `student`--11--would be assigned to `tot`).  Each time the code in the block is executed the value at the end of the block is returned to the enumerator (which is why `tot` is there).  After all the elements of the receiver `students` have been enumerated, the value of `tot` is returned by `reduce` (though you will not be making use of that).

The first time the block is called the block variables are as follows:

```
tot => 0
k   => :class1
v   => 11
```

To print

```
1) 11
```

I presume you want the label `1)` to be the right end of `:class1`.  To exact `1` from the symbol `k => :class1`, you can use the method [Symbol#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Symbol.html#method-i-5B-5D) with the regex `/\d+/`, which extracts a string of one or more digits 0-9 (as many as there are).

In reading the documentation for the method `Symbol#[]`, you will see that it converts the symbol `:class1` to the string `"class1"` and then invokes the method [String[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) on that string.

Since Ruby 1.9+, many prefer to use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) rather than `reduce`.  That method would be used like this:

```
students.each_with_object(0) do |(k,v),tot|
  tot += v
  puts k[/\d+/] + ") #{tot}"
end
```

Notice that with this method it is not necessary to return the value of the object (`tot`) to the enumerator, and that `tot` is at the end of the list of block variables, whereas it is at the beginning for `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

You were actually fairly close. You need to define the `total` variable outside of your block, just assign `0` to it using

```
total=0
```

this will make it stay through all the iterations. Then you just need a small change in

```
students.each do |key, value|
  total=total+value
  puts total
end
```

and it will do what you want.

Switching the order of `value + counter = total` is important, as assignments (through `=`) always assign to the variable on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, made some small change:-- Try this:--

```
total = 0
students.each do |key, value|
     total += value
     puts total
end
```